# Plot kernel density estimation with the kernels over the individual observations in R

Tags: r, plot, kernel-density

Well to keep things short what I want to achieve is a plot like the right one:

[image]

I would like to obtain a standard KDE plot with its individual kernels plotted over the observations.

The best solution would be the one that considers all the different kernel functions (e.g. rectangular, triangular etc).

Comment: What does the kernel over each observation represent? Some sort of uncertainty measure?

Comment: The result of a kernel is a probability density function (the red lines). The KDE is actually made up by "summing" up those kernels. Maybe, this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/exploratory-data-analysis-kernel-density-estimation-in-r-on-ozone-pollution-data-in-new-york-and-ozonopolis) helps with the understanding

Comment: Your hint helped me to calculate the single kernels, so the last thing I miss is to bring the two plots to the same scale so that it could rightfully be plotted in the same figure. Anyone any ideas in regard to that?

Comment: Please reference your sources. The plot is from here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_of_1D_histogram_and_KDE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after reading this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551610/getting-values-from-kernel-density-estimation-in-r) I managed to come up with an solution.

```
# Create some input data
x<-c(19, 20, 10, 17, 16, 13, 16, 10,  7, 18)


# Calculate the KDE
kde<-density(x,kernel="gaussian",bw=bw.SJ(x)*0.2)

# Calcualte the singel kernels/pdf's making up the KDE of all observations
A.kernel<-sapply(x, function(i) {density(i,kernel="gaussian",bw=kde$bw)},simplify=F)
sapply(1:length(A.kernel), function(i){A.kernel[[i]][['y']]<<-(A.kernel[[i]][['y']])/length(x)},simplify=F)


# Plot everything together ensuring the right scale (the area of the single kernels is corrected) 
plot(kde)
rug(x,col=2,lwd=2.5)
sapply(A.kernel, function(i){
        lines(i,col="red")}
        )
```

The result looks like this:
[image]